# Find a bug in Memory

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I was asked a question as below.

There is a **bug** in memory. The bug is, described as follows:

> By writing at **4th** location, the value is updated at **4th** location as well as at **6th** location. But writing at **6th** location is **working fine**.
>
> So, when we read from **6th** location the overwritten value comes up.

**How would you find this bug?**

My approach is described below:

1. Write all the location with `'hFF`.
2. Then apply a sequence `read - write - read` (initial `read` must give `'hFF`, thereafter `write` each location with its own address and then `read` again) at each location, starting from location `0`.
3. When we reach to **6th** location and during read command, we will get the **corrupted** value (updated by location 4) and we will find a bug.

Is there better solution to find this bug?

Comment: It's easy to design a test that catches a bug you already know about. The real problem is catching a bug you don't know is there

Comment: Yes @dave_59 I am agreed with you. The real problem is to find the unknown bugs, but this type of questions are generally asked in the interviews to check the verification and logical ability and approach to solve problems of the candidates. I've put this questions here 'coz I didn't get a chance to verify a memory so just want to know that, is there any other approach to solve this kind of bug?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you are looking for checking the validity of transaction/data. This is what I would be doing: Writing assertions for each location of memory to check if the transaction is valid in SystemVerilog and have a simple walking-through test to exercise it:

(This is an extremely simplified example of AMBA4 AHB bus protocol):

(It is checking entire memory with a memory having NUM_MEMORY_LOCATION memory locations)

```
generator
genvar i;
for(i=0;i<NUM_MEMORY_LOCATION; i++)
begin
  assert property (if(u_memory.HADDR!=i) u_memory.data[i]==$past(u_memory.data[i]) )
end
endgenerate
```

The above assertion describes: for NUM_MEMORY_LOCATION memory locations, if the address of current transaction is not the location of data specified, assert/check if data is not changed. If it changed, then give an error about this assertion/check.

You can run a test just walk through each location of memory by R/W. When the test tried to write to 4th location, because this bug triggers assertion/check for 6th location, 6th location checks and find out its value changed when it should be changed. It reports an error. Let me know anything unclear.

Comment: This is a very rough assertion, I have not run simulation to prove if it would fail for a common AHB transaction or not. But you got the intention of assertion. It is very power feature and constantly checking things behaving as the way you want, no matter whether you mean to check or not.